# If I purchase one ticket for a lottery game, what is my expected gain?

Tags: probability, lotteries

We are given a total of 3,000,000 people who buys tickets for this lottery, and each ticket costs $20. The layout for the prizes is as follows:

| Prize | # of Winners |
| --- | --- |
| 20 | 522,000 |
| 40 | 261,000 |
| 50 | 195,000 |
| 500 | 4,000 |
| 10,000 | 300 |
| 1,000,000 | 3 |

1. Calculate the the pmf of p = amount of prize for random ticket
2. If I purchase one ticket what is my expected gain?
3. If I pay an extra $10 my prize is multiplied by 2. What is my expected gain if  buy a ticket and pay an extra 10?

Solution: This is what I have so far.

For the pmf I have
p(20) = 522,000/3,000,000 = .174
p(40) = 261,000/3,000,000 = .087
p(50) = .065
p(500) = .00133
p(10,000) = .0001
p(1,000,000)=.000001

To calculate expected gain I know I have to add up the probabilities of winning each of the prizes less the cost. So the expected gain of the $20 prize would be 0(.174) because the cost of the ticket is 20 and so on... thus the expected gain would be:

$= 0(.174)+20(.087)+30(.065)+480(.00133)+9980(.0001)+999980(.000001).$

Is that correct? The question continues to ask:

Suppose that I continue to buy tickets until I win a prize (of any amount). After I win a prize, I will not buy any more tickets. Let T be the number of tickets that I will buy.

1. Find the pmf of T if the tickets are not independent of each other
2. Under the assumption of independence, what is the distribution of T? Write the pmf. How many tickets would I expect to buy?

Any suggestions for these last two questions?

Comment: "Question continues to ask:..." should begin another post, with a link back to this one.

Comment: @user1147844 Please do not make cosmetic edits to old questions. That puts them at the head of the active question queue and wastes the time of people who follow that queue.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly.   You forgot to include "not winning any prize", which still costs the ticket price so has a very probable negative gain.

Comment: how to I include this loss in the equation?

Comment: $+(-20)(\tfrac{982,303}{3,000,000})$ or simply don't subtract the ticket price until after weighting all the prizes.

Comment: It's easier to calculate $\mathbb{E}[\text{Gain}]=\mathbb{E}[\text{Winnings}]-20$, first because you won't forget your 0, then because knowing $\mathbb{E}[\text{Winnings}]$ independent of price is always useful.

Comment: Precisely so. $\ddot\smile$

Comment: so it would be E=  20(.174) + 40(.087) + 50 (.065) + 500(.00133)+ 10000(.0001) + 1,000,000(.000001) - 20

Comment: Yes.  Though I would also advise against doing the division until after the sum to reduce rounding errots. $$\frac{20(522000)+\overset{\text{etc.}}{\ldots}+1000000(3)}{3000000}-20$$

Comment: is it possible to get a negative number?

Comment: Possible?  It's how lotteries make a profit.